# Building new dataframe from series

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Taking another crack at an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405508/extracting-data-from-pandas-dataframe-as-dataframe/19405604?noredirect=1#19405604) of mine since I still do not understand how to properly do what I want.

I have data stored in a dataframe and need to extract averaged chunks of it to use later.  My index is datetime values, but this is not terribly important.  Unfortunately, I cannot do a simple df.resample() operation, since the data I need to extract is not regularly spaced.  Example:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import *

# Build example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=random.rand(10,3),index=None,columns=list('ABC'))

# Build dummy dataframe to store averaged data from "df"
dummy = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

# Perform averaging of "df" 
for r in xrange(1,10,2):
    ave = df.ix[r-1:r+1].mean()

    # Store averaged data in dummy dataframe
    # Here is where I hit my problem, since ave is a Series
    dummy = dummy.append(ave)
```

I cannot append a series to dataframe.
I can work around by converting ave to a dictionary, then appending to dummy:

```
for r in xrange(1,10,2):
    ave = df.ix[r-1:r+1].mean().to_dict()
    ave = pd.DataFrame(ave,index=[r])
    dummy = dummy.append(ave)
```

First: does my overall goal make sense?
Second: Is there a better way to achieve this?  Converting to dictionary, then dataframe, then appending seems kludgey, but it is the best I have.

***Begin Edit***
unutbu raised a good point.  As written, rolling_mean() will work.  But, I am interested only in very few rows of data, everything else is considered garbage.

```
# Now creating larger dataframe for illustration
df = pd.DataFrame(data=random.rand(10000,3),index=None,columns=list('ABC'))

# Now, most of the data are not averaged
for r in xrange(1,10000,50):
    ave = df.ix[r-1:r+1].mean().to_dict()
    ave = pd.DataFrame(ave,index=[r])
```

The main problem I have with my examples is showing the irregularity with which the averaging is done.  The averaging is event driven (i.e. if something happened at 2013-01-01 14:23 then average the data about 2013-01-01 14:23 +/- 2.5min.

Unfortunately, the data timestamps are also highly irregular, which makes rolling_mean() ineffective in this case.  So I have irregular events determining when I should average my irregularly recorded data, making a nice problem.

I can achieve what I want, but only by converting ave from series to dictionary, then to dataframe.  Perhaps in this case "good enough" should be let alone.

***End Edit***
        dummy = dummy.append(ave)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you are looking for is [pd.rolling_mean](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
# Build example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(10,3), index=None, columns=list('ABC'))
print(df)
#           A         B         C
# 0  0.417022  0.720324  0.000114
# 1  0.302333  0.146756  0.092339
# 2  0.186260  0.345561  0.396767
# 3  0.538817  0.419195  0.685220
# 4  0.204452  0.878117  0.027388
# 5  0.670468  0.417305  0.558690
# 6  0.140387  0.198101  0.800745
# 7  0.968262  0.313424  0.692323
# 8  0.876389  0.894607  0.085044
# 9  0.039055  0.169830  0.878143

dummy = pd.rolling_mean(df, window=3).dropna()
print(dummy)
```

yields

```
          A         B         C
2  0.301872  0.404214  0.163073
3  0.342470  0.303837  0.391442
4  0.309843  0.547624  0.369792
5  0.471245  0.571539  0.423766
6  0.338436  0.497841  0.462274
7  0.593039  0.309610  0.683919
8  0.661679  0.468711  0.526037
9  0.627902  0.459287  0.551836
```

Comment: Not quite.  As written in my example rolling_mean will work.  But I do not need all of the data.  I will edit my post to show an example.

Comment: @ubuntu: do you want `dummy = pd.rolling_mean(df, window=3).shift(-1).dropna()` to have the window centered at the current observation rather than ending on the current observation? Or, if you prefer, you could do `dummy = pd.rolling_mean(df, window=3, center=True).dropna()` Also, depending on the setting, it might be useful to set `min_periods=3` to force out the edge cases.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way with a datelike index.

```
In [67]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(10,3), index=None, columns=list('ABC'))

In [68]: df
Out[68]: 
          A         B         C
0  0.417022  0.720324  0.000114
1  0.302333  0.146756  0.092339
2  0.186260  0.345561  0.396767
3  0.538817  0.419195  0.685220
4  0.204452  0.878117  0.027388
5  0.670468  0.417305  0.558690
6  0.140387  0.198101  0.800745
7  0.968262  0.313424  0.692323
8  0.876389  0.894607  0.085044
9  0.039055  0.169830  0.878143
```

This is a regular index, but irregular in time (or at least pretend)

```
In [69]: df.index=date_range('20130101 09:00:58',periods=10,freq='s')

In [70]: df
Out[70]: 
                            A         B         C
2013-01-01 09:00:58  0.417022  0.720324  0.000114
2013-01-01 09:00:59  0.302333  0.146756  0.092339
2013-01-01 09:01:00  0.186260  0.345561  0.396767
2013-01-01 09:01:01  0.538817  0.419195  0.685220
2013-01-01 09:01:02  0.204452  0.878117  0.027388
2013-01-01 09:01:03  0.670468  0.417305  0.558690
2013-01-01 09:01:04  0.140387  0.198101  0.800745
2013-01-01 09:01:05  0.968262  0.313424  0.692323
2013-01-01 09:01:06  0.876389  0.894607  0.085044
2013-01-01 09:01:07  0.039055  0.169830  0.878143
```

Take every 3s of data (whether its their or not) and mean it (or you could do fancier if you want). Their are a bunch more options (e.g. which side to include, where to put the labels etc, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling)

```
In [71]: df.resample('3s',how=lambda x: x.mean())
Out[71]: 
                            A         B         C
2013-01-01 09:00:57  0.359677  0.433540  0.046226
2013-01-01 09:01:00  0.309843  0.547624  0.369792
2013-01-01 09:01:03  0.593039  0.309610  0.683919
2013-01-01 09:01:06  0.457722  0.532219  0.481593
```